# How do I subscribe to changes in the Login

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a navbar menu component which has optional links that depend on whether or not the user is logged in.  In my current setup the navbar checks the login status (via the LoginService) on initialisation.  Here is the **NavMenuComponent.ts**:

```
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;
  isNavbarCollapsed = true;

  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelper, private loginService: LoginService) {

    this.subscription = loginService.checkLoginStatus.subscribe(
      isLoggedIn => {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.checkLoginStatus();
    this.isLoggedIn = this.loginService.checkLoginStatus();
  }

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}
```

**I want the navbar menu component to react if the user logs in or out.**  That means publishing an event in either my in the LoginService or the LoginComponent which the navbar is subscribed.  You can see that I have tried to write a subcription in the navbar menu, which doesn't work!

How should I get it to work?

**Edit**: Here's the loginService:

```
export class LoginService {
  //isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelper) { }

  //checkLoginStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
   checkLoginStatus(): boolean {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    if (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)){
      //console.log(this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token));
      alert("user is logged in");
      //this.isLoggedIn = true;

      return true;
    }
    else {
      //this.isLoggedIn = false;
      alert("user is NOT logged in");
      return false;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `loginService.checkLoginStatus` is an `Observable` that is going to push new `boolean` values in either `true` or `false` as soon as the user performs login or logout, you can simply use that.

Actually, you're already using it. So whenever there's a change in the login state of the user, the `isLoggedIn` property on your Component will update. So you should be able to directly use it in your template.

Also, since that is the case, there's no need for the code that you have in `ngOnInit`. As a matter of fact, you can move your `constructor` code to `ngOnInit` and refactor your code a bit. Something like this:

```
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;
  isNavbarCollapsed = true;

  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper, 
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = loginService.checkLoginStatus
      .subscribe(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn);
  }

  ...
}
```

#### UPDATE:

I think you should create a `private` `BehaviorSubject` in your `LoginService` which you're then going to expose `asObservable` publicly. Now, once the user logs in, just call `.next(true)` on this private `BehaviorSubject` and when the user logs out, call `.next(true)`.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class LoginService {

  private isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelper) {}

  ...

  // When Login
  this.isLoggedIn.next(true) 

  ...

  // When Logout
  this.isLoggedIn.next(false)

  /* checkLoginStatus(): boolean {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) ? this.isLoggedIn.next(true): this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
  } */
}
```

You can then `subscribe` to the `public` `Observable` the usual way in your Component.

Something like this:

```
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;
  isNavbarCollapsed = true;

  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper, 
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.isLoggedIn$
      .subscribe(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @siddajmera, I've updated by question with the LoginService.  How do I make the loginservice Observable?

Comment: @Winthorpe, updated my answer. Please check to see if that helps.

Comment: '    this.subscription = loginService.checkLoginStatus
      .subscribe(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn);'  I get an red line under loginService or under subscribe if I change to this.loginService?

Comment: @Winthorpe, you'll have to `subscribe` to `isLoggedIn$` instead of `checkLoginStatus `

Comment: @Winthorpe, also be sure to get rid of `checkLoginStatus` method from the `LoginService` as it won't be required anymore. Like I explained in my answer, you should call `this.isLoggedIn.next(true)` once the user has logged in and `this.isLoggedIn.next(false)` once the user has logged out and this should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Below LoginService may be help you as I have added  loggedStatus eventemitter object. So when user log in or log out based on that particular value we are emitting and same value we will get in Nav component.

```
export class LoginService {
      //isLoggedIn: boolean;
      loggedStatus = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

      constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelper) { }

      //checkLoginStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
       checkLoginStatus(): boolean {
        var token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

        if (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)){
          //console.log(this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token));
          alert("user is logged in");
          //this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.loggedStatus.emit(true);
          return true;
        }
        else {
          //this.isLoggedIn = false;
          alert("user is NOT logged in");
          this.loggedStatus.emit(false);
          return false;

        }
      }
    }
```

Nav Component Change

Below code you can implement in the ngOnInit method.

```
this.loginService.loggedStatus.subscribe(
      isLoggedIn => {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn
      });
```

Comment: But a value won't be emitted without calling `checkLoginStatus`

Comment: Once either on app initialisation or on login or on logout we needs to call checkloginstatus anyhow.. so that time only we are emitting so nav component gets to know.